# viso2 couldn't find mono_odometer node

Tags: ros, viso2, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I download viso2 and build using rosmake. There was no error.
However when I run it with following launch file.

```
<!-- example launch file for mono_odometer -->
<launch>
  <arg name="camera"/> <!-- camera must be set at launch -->
  <node name="image_proc" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" ns="$(arg camera)"/>
  <node name="mono_odometer" pkg="viso2_ros" type="mono_odometer" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="$(arg camera)/image_rect" />
    <param name="camera_height" value="0.5" /> <!-- cam is 0.5m above ground -->
    <param name="camera_pitch" value="0.0" /> <!-- cam is looking straight forward -->
  </node>
</launch>
```

It gave this error "ERROR: cannot launch node of type [viso2_ros/mono_odometer]: can't locate node [mono_odometer] in package [viso2_ros]"

How could I fix this problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61399/viso2-couldn%27t-find-mono_odometer-node/) by [Maytheewat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4743/maytheewat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, check if the executable is there:

```
rosrun viso2_ros mono_odometer
```

This should give no error.
If the executable cannot be found it may be not compiled. If you are on a fuerte branch, use `rosmake viso2_ros` to compile the package. For the groovy branches, run `catkin_make` in your catkin workspace to compile the package.

Check if viso2_ros can be found by rospack: `rospack find viso2_ros`. If rospack cannot find the package, add the path to your environment variable `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` or source the `setup.bash` of your `<catkin_workspace>/devel` directory.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maytheewat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4743/maytheewat/) on 2013-04-23**:
There is no /bin/ folder after I run rosmake and viso2_ros was found by rospack find viso2_ros

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-04-23**:
Please post the full output of the command `rosmake viso2_ros` (e.g. via pastebin.com).

**Comment by [Maytheewat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4743/maytheewat/) on 2013-04-23**:
http://pastebin.com/QYS8kUp6

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-04-23**:
Which branch are you using? There seems to be a ROS_NOBUILD file in your viso2_ros which does not belong there. Note: if you are on the groovy or groovy-devel branch you have to use catkin instead of rospack to build the package.

**Comment by [Maytheewat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4743/maytheewat/) on 2013-04-23**:
Hmm....yes I'm on groovy, I'll try to use catkin then, Thank you very much

**Comment by [Maytheewat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4743/maytheewat/) on 2013-04-23**:
By the way, do you have any advice how to do this (use catkin to build a package) I don't have any experience doing this before

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-04-23**:
Please read http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Create_a_ROS_Workspace You'll have to put the viso2 repository in your `catkin_ws/src` directory.